# Android Issue with activity context

Tags: java, android

So I have a helper class that reuses a lot of code through out the application, one of the methods is shown below:

```
public void setTitleTextSize(final int id){
    infoButton = ((Activity) context).findViewById(R.id.info_button);

    ViewTreeObserver customTitleScale = infoButton.getViewTreeObserver();

    customTitleScale.addOnPreDrawListener(new OnPreDrawListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onPreDraw() {
            int infoWidth = infoButton.getMeasuredWidth();
            if(infoWidth !=0){
                if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11.0){
                    TypedValue tv = new TypedValue();
                    ((Activity) context).getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.actionBarSize, tv, true);
                    actionBarWidth = ((Activity) context).getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(tv.resourceId);
                }

                DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
                Display Screen = ((Activity) context).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
                Screen.getMetrics(metrics);
                int screenWidth = metrics.widthPixels;

                int titleWidth = screenWidth - infoWidth - actionBarWidth;

                TextView titleText = (TextView) ((Activity) context).findViewById(R.id.title_text);
                titleText.setText(id);

                TextPaint paint = titleText.getPaint();
                Rect rect = new Rect();
                String text = String.valueOf(titleText.getText());
                int textLength = text.length();
                paint.getTextBounds(text, 0, textLength, rect);

                if(rect.width() > titleWidth){

                    float scale = (float) titleWidth / (float) rect.width();
                    float textSize = titleText.getTextSize();       
                    float scaleSize = (float) (textSize * (scale*0.8));     
                    titleText.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, scaleSize);

                }
                infoButton.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

I use this particular method on all of my activities.

The problem I've got is I don't want to display the `infoButton` on every activity but when I add `View infoButton = findViewById(R.id.info_button); infoButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);` to the activity, the screen is just black.

So I was thinking on how to do this and the only thing I can thing of is to pass a boolean into the method stating whether the info view is visible or not. I suppose I'd do an if statement saying `if true then display it, if false then don't but I can't figure out how to do this.

Any help would be amazing thanks.

Comment: Can't you just add a `boolean` parameter to `setTitleTextSize()` that when `true`, should set `infoButton`'s visibility to `View.VISIBLE` and `View.GONE` otherwise?

Comment: Yes and that's what I've done, but the problem I've got is the screen just shows black on the activities that have got the visibility set to `GONE`, can't understand why

Comment: It shouldn't be anything related to *that* `View`, is it possible that "under" that `View` there's a black background, a black image or so?

Comment: no, it does it on all three activities I don't want the `imageButton` to show and in the logcat I can't see anything that could be the issue

Comment: I can see a message in the logcat that says `Attemted to finish an input event but the input event reciever has already been disposed.`

Comment: Seems to not have anything to do with it. Could you post a screenshot?

Comment: I was thinking that it could be because I'm running it on the main thread, so I'm going to split it out into a runnable and run it on the ui thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue I was having, My logic wasn't correct for the `if` statement `if(infoWidth !=0)`. The code wasn't running if the  activity didn't have an info button because the infoWidth would always be zero. So I changed the logic to `if(infoWidth !=0 || !displayInfoButton)` which works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use method infoButton.getVisibility()
it will return you the integer to get visibility status of you widget.